# Adding tag to external links

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyway I can amend the .htaccess file or add a little php to apend all outbound links with an id.

e.g. www.example.com/&this_is_the_id

Really appreciate your inputs! Using Wordpress.

Update:

I've tried this -

```
 <script>

$(".class").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '&_my_id';
});
    </script>
```

Comment: .htaccess is used for parsing incoming requests. I don't think it has anything to do with outgoing links within your HTML. There might be some WordPress plugin to do something like this, because there are also plugins adding an icon to all outgoing links.

Comment: You want to add the parameter to all external links or just the links in the post content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".class").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '&id_mine';
});
```

The above was all i needed in the end. Thanks for looking all